# Correction of answer on AskUbuntu

Tags: discussion

I have followed an answer on [Create OpenSUSE bootable USB stick from Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/750024/create-opensuse-bootable-usb-stick-from-ubuntu). I have copy-pasted the command and found out that there is a typo `zenity --into --text="DONE"` instead of `zenity --info --text="DONE"`. So I tried to edit the answer to correct it. But it says that the edit must be at least 6 characters. So what should I do?

p.s. I have found out about typo after running the command and waiting for the popup DONE.

Comment: This is more for meta, but I'd just change the wording a bit if it is to get the six chars.

Comment: As @JacobVlijm said, this question belongs to meta. Meanwhile, I have fixed the typo.

Comment: Well, when you edit something and you can't save the edit because it doesn't sum all the 6 characters, you can see if you can make other minor changes to the text without actually changing the meaning. For example, if in the text there is a line saying "Here is the image", you can reformulate it as "In this  screenshot you can see the above mentioned error". If the text contains "Thank, John", or "regards, Al" you can delete those words. You can scan the text for a missed article or some forgotten commas, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: And yes, this is more like Meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Errare humanum est* - it is human to err, and some times errors do sneak into our answers.

There's a few things you can do if you find an error in an answer.

1. Leave a comment. Chances are the person whose answer contains errors is high reputation user and is frequently visiting this site ( like myself . . .and sometimes visiting too frequently :) They will see your comment and edit the answer.
2. Request assistance from high reputation users. You can do so in [AskUbuntu chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) or here on Meta site.
3. If you have sufficient reputation on the site and have editing privilege, you can correct the post yourself.
4. If you have flagging privilege, flag for moderator attention. That's least preferred solution, since our dear moderators are busy swinging ban hammers at misbehaving users as well as moving questions that are not related to Ubuntu :) and it would be shame to trouble them too much with trivial things ( at least IMHO ). However, as a last resort that's as good solution as any.

As for the 6 character limit, there's always a way to paraphrase  a sentence, change grammar, and use synonyms for words to add up to the character limit without loosing the meaning. Remember: as long as your edit doesn't damage the meaning of the answer, your edit is good to go.

Comment: Comment also needs some reputation. Suggesting edit is the action which everyone can do afaik :)

Comment: Yes, comments need reputation but not that much.  Comments need  50 reputations on the site, http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment  Participating in meta comes at 5 rep  , so that's probably the simplest one.  I don't know about suggested edits, though

Comment: ***Don't*** flag for moderator attention over a minor factual edit. Flag a mod when it's rude or abusive, when someone is making spam, funny business, etc in *edits* (but flag spam posts as spam), or for edit wars.

Comment: @cat   If there is no high reputation users around,  then mods are next in line.  If you are low-reputation user, you won't be able to edit and comments don't show up  in any queue ( meaning there's no separate queue for comments ). Besides, mods are not excluded from reviewing edits

Answer (score 5):

This frequently happens.  There is an issue in a post, and the edit just won't line up to 6 bytes or more.  Here are several ideas:

1. Check for grammar and spelling.  You can nitpick in this situation.  Put two spaces between sentences, even though it doesn't show.  Check for missing apostrophes.
2. Check formatting.  Is there somewhere where the user used bold where back-ticks would have been more appropriate?  Look for trailing new lines.
3. Change wording.  If nothing else works, simply in-obstructively change the wording; you can always find something that *could* be improved, even slightly.

Please do do one thing, though.

## Let people know what you're doing.

Don't edit out a critical error and then mark in the comment, `Fixed grammar and formatting.`  Mark that you edited out the critical error, and even, if it's not very obvious, drop a **friendly** comment to the author.  It can't hurt, and it will prevent potential roll-back wars.

Comment: _“Put two spaces between sentences”_ Please don’t change the spaces unless there is no other chance. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_spacing, 3rd paragraph.

Comment: Good point, @Melebius.  This should just be as a last resort.